# AWS CloudFront Edge Cache Expiry Logic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Users upload profile pics to my website. The path for "user 150" is:

`www.website.com/pics/150.jpg`

If a user changes their profile pic, the OLD one will be stuck in the Edge Cache until expiry. How can I load the NEW profile pic into the Edge Cache after it is uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is make sure all uploads have a random key for the filename. (something like a UUID)

Instead of simply constructing the path to the file when needed, store the entire path in relation to the user.

Comment: So, instead of the above path have: `www.website.com/user150/1.jpg`, `www.website.com/user150/2.jpg`.. etc. for the different uploads? Then I would run a DB query (or loop the folder) for the most recent pic?

Comment: A [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) that changes each time, or a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) such that the value changes each time the file is updated would be preferable, but as long as you change it and store the new value in the database, you should be good.  You don't want to loop the folder; that's costly and time-consuming. Random keys in the filename becomes more important for scaling above 100 uploads per second on a consistent basis.